# Getting a size_type that is guaranteed to work for indexing through vectors of different types

Tags: c++

Let's say I have two types, `Class1` and `Class2`. Then I create two vectors:

```
vector<Class1> vec1;
vector<Class2> vec2;
//create vec1 and vec2, such that both have the same number of elements
for (vector<Class1>::size_type i=0; i!=vec1.size(); ++i) {
  c1 = vec1[i];
  c2 = vec2[i]; //BAD?
  //do something
}
```

You probably get the picture. Isn't it bad in this case to rely on the `size_type` for `vector<Class2>` being the same as the one for `vector<Class1>`?

In these cases, where you have two same-sized vectors containing objects of different types, yet they are related enough to warrant looping through both of them, how can this problem be resolved?

I know it's unlikely that I'll ever hit high enough integers to ever run into problems, but still, I want to write good, robust, C++ code. Maybe I should look at both `size_type`s and take the minimum of them? Is that the way to go? Sounds like a strange practice to me.

Comment: What is the actual problem that needs resolving? Both variables are using `std::vector`. It does not matter what data type is stored in each vector. `std::vector::size_type` will be the same data type in all cases. It is the data type that `std::vector` uses internally to count its items and provide indexed access to them. If both vectors are the same size, then index 0, index 1, etc are exactly the same in both vectors. If they are not the same size, then yes, you would have to take the minimum size of the two vectors so you do not access higher indexes in the smaller vector.

Comment: *"... objects of different types, yet they are related enough to warrant looping through both of them, how can this problem be resolved?"* How is that a problem in the first place?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Oh, then that is the answer then! I didn't realize that `size_type` was a part of the template. I thought it was dependent on the type used. But if this is the case, I find it rather puzzling why the we have to write things like `vector<int>::size_type` all the time. Why should we have to mention the type?

Comment: @DennisRitchie: That's not entirely correct. The `container::size_type` really comes from the allocator for the container. As you have it above, both will use `std::Allocator<T>`, but if you had containers with different allocators, they could also have different `size_type`s.

Comment: You could of course use iterators instead, and not bother with indexing. :-) But unless you have "accidentally" specialized `std::vector<Class2>` or `std::allocator<Class2>`, there will be no problem in practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `std::allocator` defines `size_type` as `size_t`, so you can assume `size_type` as `size_t` ***iif*** you can guarantee there are no custom allocators that define a different type for their `size_type`s.

However you take the risk of someone coming back later and adding a custom allocator that may be incompatible with this assumption.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is guaranteed by the standard or not, but I'd expect all `vector::size_type` types to be identical no matter what template parameter you choose.

Comment: Unless someone writes a custom allocator defining a different type for it, which I believe should be discouraged. +1 nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

I think, at least in theory, what you want here is something like:

```
std::common_type<std::vector<classA>::size_type, 
                 std::vector<classB>::size_type>::type i;

for (i=0; i!=vec1.size(); i++)
    // ...
```

I doubt you'll see that on a regular basis in most code though (nor, most likely, be the toast of the Christmas party for writing it either).